# PowerShell : error handling when using -asjob parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, dsc

I can't figure out how to get the computernames that did not respond when using `-asjob`, could someone advise?

```
try{
    gwmi "Win32_OperatingSystem" -ComputerName $ordis -asjob  
    $resu=get-job | ? {$_.psjobtypename -eq "wmijob" } |wait-job |receive-job
}
catch{"error"}
$resu | select PSCOMPUTERNAME, @{name="lastboottime";expression={$_.converttodatetime($_.lastbootuptime)}} |sort lastboottime |ft
remove-job * -force
```

some hosts failed with the following error but I don't know which ones

> Le serveur RPC n'est pas disponible. (Exception de HRESULT :
> 0x800706BA)
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult : (:) [], COMException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobStateFailed

Comment: For such scripts I use a CSV file with computer names. `Import-CSV` yield a collection to iterate. I save query results in another collection, then update the CSV fields (for hosts that responded) and save it with Export-CSV.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht you're not taking the benefits of parallel processing like this

Comment: I use parallel processing for queries. Processing the results takes negligible time. If you're interested I can post my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another line to capture failed jobs after `$resu | select..` statement, try/catch is not going to work as you are spawning wmi queries into separate run spaces.

```powershell
....
Get-Job -State Failed | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Location
remove-job * -force
```

Comment: I had to loop through childjobs to get the information : `get-job -state failed |select -expand childjobs | ?{$_.state -eq "failed"} |select -expand location`